# MySQL how to get 50% of end date based on another value?

Tags: mysql, sql

Fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJTJnftZvbDsnoYT2RNSVJ/0

I need to add specific number of days to the current date, then return 50% date.

How can I add the `days` to `today's date` and return 50% of the date?

So the first row output from DB Fiddle link would be: `2020-03-24` because from `today's date plus 100 = 2020-05-13` and  `50%` of `100` is `2020-03-24`

Visual output:

```
days    todayDate      50%
100    2020/02/03   2020-03-24
```

How can this be achieved on MySQL?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "50% of end date"? Please share sample input data and your queries here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just add half the number of days?

```
select curdate() + interval (100 * 0.5) day
-----------------------------^ number of days
-----------------------------------^ 50%
```